# General formula for the integral of $f(s)^k$ with respect to $s$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider the definite integral

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}=\int_{-\infty}^t f(s)^k\mathop{ds}.
\end{equation}

In terms of $F(t):=\int_{0}^t f(s)\mathop{}ds$, is there a simple expression for $\mathcal{I}$? It seems to me that at least a solution with sufficient restrictions of $f$ should exist which is similar in nature to the reverse chain rule: $\int f(s)^kf'(s)\mathop{ds}=f(s)^{k+1}/(k+1)+C$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the answer is simply "no", unfortunately.

Comment: @GregMartin Well that's a pity, perhaps a Taylor series expansion could work?

Comment: Surely there's a function $f$ such that $\int f$ is elementary but $\int f^2$ isn't, but I'm not coming up with one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple formula like that.

Example:  $f(x) = x e^{x^2}$.  Then
$$
A := \int f(x)\;dx = \frac{e^{x^2}}{2}+C
$$
is an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), but
$$
B := \int f(x)^2\;dx = \frac{xe^{2x^2}}{4} + \frac{i\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}(i\sqrt{2}\,x)}{8\sqrt{2}} +C_1
$$
is not an elementary function.
So, in articular, $B$ cannot be written in terms of $A$ and elementary operations (add, multiply, exponential, log, trig, inverse trig, algebraic function,...)

---

A related example:
$f(x) = x^{-1/2}$, where $\int f(x)\;dx = 2\sqrt{x} +C$ is an algebraic function, but $\int(f(x))^2\;dx = \log(x)+C_1$ is not an algebraic function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, could a series expansion hold ([see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+f%28s%29%5Ek+ds))?